# Creating a human model in a web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, expression-blend, silverlight-5.0

I am looking forward to create a web application which allows user to generate 3D human models. When user gives the particular measurements, respective model should be generated.

I am planning to do this in .net platform. I have few questions.

1. What are the possible tools and languages
2. Is there any library for .net (visual studio 2012) to create a human model at the application run time

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is very little information here.  There are lots of 3D modelling tools out there, have you looked at any of those?  If so, what are your thoughts about them and what additional work do you want to do?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am planning to make a virtual fitting room and in order to do that need to generate a human model according to the user inputs.
ex- If change the waist size, should visually indicate the changes

Answer (score 5):

Forgive me, but it sounds like you're underestimating the difficulty of this project.

I'll give you some answers in earnest:

If you're showing 3D models in Silverlight, you're likely going to want to [check out this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh547098.aspx).

Generating realistic human models is NOT a trivial task.  I have never heard of anyone doing this on the fly before, so you have a long road ahead of you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was just wondering there any libraries out there since this is a hard task